# How can I manipulate an object derived from a JSON response before my angular view is updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, controller

I've run into a scenario where I need to take the following JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "url":"http://myurl1",
        "tags":"tag 1.1,tag1.2,tag1.3"
    },
    {
        "url":"http://myurl2",
        "tags":"tag 2.1,tag2.2"
    }
]
```

And end up with:

```
<a href="http://myurl1">tag 1.1</a>
<a href="http://myurl1">tag 1.2</a>
<a href="http://myurl1">tag 1.3</a>

<a href="http://myurl2">tag 2.1</a>
<a href="http://myurl2">tag 2.2</a>
```

I've built this in jQuery by simply storing the url during each loop, splitting the tags into an array which I then loop through to output to the `<a>` tags while pulling in the previously stored single instance of URL. I'm REALLY trying hard to switch to angular though and here is basically what I have. I have a feeling that I'm overly complicating this, believe it or not I've searched for a long time and have banged on this for a few hours.

If the json data was flat, I'd be done, but since it isn't I'm stuck.

I've got this, which is fine and all but it dumps all of the tags into a single `<a>` element, not what I need. I'm assuming I wouldn't create a nested loop in here so onto the controller:

**Markup:**

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="TagCtrl">
        <a ng-repeat="tag in tags" href="{{tag.url}}">{{tag.tags}}</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller("TagCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data/tags.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.tags = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
    });
});
```

I just don't know where I'm to split that tags data into an array and loop through it, even if I did, how do I get that back to the view? My gut tells me that this should be in a directive but I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible for now.

One last thing, I don't have the ability to change the JSON structure.

Comment: Not sure I totally understand, but do you just want arrays or strings in the tags instead of one string?

Comment: And you`ng-repeat` on `tags`, but your controller uses `posts`, are these different?

Comment: Can you wrap each group of links in a div?

Comment: @Lucas I'd like each tag to have a wrapping <a> tag. Also, thanks for the catch on the posts, fixed it!

Comment: I guess my question is: do you want the list of <a>'s to have any separation based on which url they belong to, or should they just be all together? Your HTML seems to indicate the latter, though you inserted a newline in the HTML between groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.tags = [];
    data.forEach(function(urlObject) {
        // Get array of tags from the string of tags
        var tagsList = urlObject.tags.split(',');
        tagsList.forEach(function(tag) {
             $scope.tags.push({
                url: urlObject.url,
                tag: tag
             });    
        });
    });
})
```

and then use the same HTML you have.

Answer (score 0):

From your json response (let's call it `data`):

```
var tags = [];

// Loop on every response item
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  // Get all tags from this response item
  var splits = data[i].tags.split(',');

  for (var j = 0; j < splits.length; j++) {
    tags.push({url: data[i].url, tag: splits[i]});
  }
}

// Put the array into our scope
$scope.tags = tags;
```

Then you can use your template:

```
<a ng-repeat="tag in tags" href="{{tag.url}}">{{tag.tag}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are trying to display a value which does not yet exist on $scope. i.e. "tag". The only variable on $scope is posts. If you want to continue in the current fashion your html would need to be as such:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="TagCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <a ng-repeat="tag in post.tags" href="{{post.url}}">{{tag}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

However this will not split your tags out. I haven't tested this but it should work:

```
(function(){
    app.controller('tagCtrl', tagCtrl);

    tagCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
    function tagCtrl($scope, $http){
        $scope.posts = [];

        $http.get('data/tags.json')
             .success(function(data){
                $scope.posts = data;
                $scope.posts.forEach(function(post){
                    post.splitTags = post.tags.split(",");
                });
             })
             .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // log error
              });
    }
})();

<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="tagCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <a ng-repeat="tag in post.splitTags" href="{{post.url}}">{{tag}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```